# How to add Vertical Space Constraint to an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not sure what is wrong! I am simply trying to add a vertical space constraint from an UIImageView to the ContentView but I never see that option. You can see I have added vertical space constraint from UIImageView the top of UIImageView to the ContentView but I am unable to add from UIImageVie to the bottom of the contentview.

[image]

With the above constraints here is the result: [image]

Comment: Start here: [Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html)
Also you can try "Adding Missing or Suggested Constraints" or even "Reset to suggested constraints" to clear up the warnings.

Comment: Adding Missing or Suggested constraints put wrong constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a constraint from the bottom of this image view to the bottom of the content view then:

1) Select the image view

2) Click 'editor' from the Xcode menu

3) However over 'pin'

4) Select 'bottom space to superview' - Your superview in this case is the content view of the cell

[image]

Note there are other ways of achieving the same result.

Edit:

You can also try

1) Control click on the image view

2) Drag downward to the bottom of the content view and release.

3) You should be presented with a small black box pop up that provides constraint options like bottom space to content margin or bottom space to superview.  You can then select the create constraints and edit as necessary in the size inspector.

[image]

Comment: After I click on the pin I do not see any option that say bottom space to superview.

Comment: I've tried adding some additional screen shots and another method

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be square, set the aspect ratio constraint for the UIImageView to be 1:1.

This requires you to set either a width, or a height constraint for the image or you need to pin the bottom of the image to its containing view and have the containing view have a height.

So:

If you know the height you want for your image, add a height constraint and set the aspect ratio to 1:1 for the image view. If you want a different aspect, set it to that aspect ratio.

If you want the image height to be determined from something outside like a cell height, pin the top and bottom of the image view to the containing view which should have some sort of constraint which sets its size. Here the image will grow to the height the containing view imposes on it and its width will scale to match based on the aspect ration you set.